# How to install lib mod_auth_cas.so in apache2 server in Mac OS

Tags: macos-sierra

I try to google information on how to install mod_auth_cas.so with apache2 web server in MacOS, It is hard to find the right now.

One common page I found, I need to compile the mod_auth_cas.so from the source code manually from github https://github.com/apereo/mod_auth_cas/tree/master

I follow the steps

```
autoreconf -ivf
```

Build is performed with the standard Autoconf incantation:

```
./configure && make && sudo make install
```

It always gets the error.

```
    checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
configure: Locating apxs
checking for --with-apxs... no
checking for apxs... no
checking for apxs2... no
configure: error: in `/Users/sopheamak/Documents/mod_auth_cas':
configure: error: apxs not found
```